# $unwind empty array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of users where each document has following structure:

```
{
  "_id": "<id>",
  "login": "xxx",
  "solved": [
    {
      "problem": "<problemID>",
      "points": 10
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

The field `solved` may be empty or contain arbitrary many subdocuments. My goal is to get a list of users together with the total score (sum of `points`) where users that haven't solved any problem yet will be assigned total score of 0. Is this possible to do this with a single query (ideally using aggregation framework)?

I was trying to use following query in aggregation framework:

```
{ "$group": {
  "_id": "$_id",
  "login": { "$first": "$login" },
  "solved": { "$addToSet": { "points": 0 } }
} }
{ "$unwind": "$solved" }
{ "$group": {
  "_id": "$_id",
  "login": { "$first": "$login" },
  "solved": { "$sum": "$solved.points" }
} }
```

However I am getting following error:

```
exception: The top-level _id field is the only field currently supported for exclusion
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: when you say "solved may be empty" is it present and an empty array or is it absent in case of no problems solved?

Comment: also, $first login gets the first value (by order of array) - is that what you want, or do you want $min?  If no problems are solved, can login be null or missing also?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

With MongoDB 3.2 version and newer, the **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)** operator now has some options where in particular the `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` option will solve this.

If this option is set to true and if the path is null, missing, or an empty array, **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)** outputs the document. If false, **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)** does not output a document if the path is null, missing, or an empty array. In your case, set it to true:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": {
        "path": "$solved",
        "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
    } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "login": { "$first": "$login" },
        "solved": { "$sum": "$solved.points" }
    } }
])
```

Comment: Wow. Classic _if-true-work-much-better-than-the-unreasonable-default_ flag :/

Answer (score 8):

Here is the solution - it assumes that the field "solved" is either absent, is equal to null or has an array of problems and scores solved.   The case it does not handle is "solved" being an empty array - although that would be a simple additional adjustment you could add.

```
project = {$project : {
        "s" : {
            "$ifNull" : [
                "$solved",
                [
                    {
                        "points" : 0
                    }
                ]
            ]
        },
        "login" : 1
    }
};
unwind={$unwind:"$s"};
group= { "$group" : {
        "_id" : "$_id",
        "login" : {
            "$first" : "$login"
        },
        "score" : {
            "$sum" : "$s.points"
        }
    }
}
```

`db.students.aggregate( [ project, unwind, group ] );`

Comment: Hello @AsyaKamsky , I've tried your codes on MongoDB 3.0.3 however $ifNull doesn't work exactly? Also I couldn't anything about this issue on http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/#exp._S_ifNull .

Comment: Instead, I've used `'s': { $cond: [{$eq: [{$size: '$solved'}, 0] }, [ { point: 0 } ], '$solved'] }` <br> and I reported on Jira.

Comment: $size did not exist when this answer was written, so I couldn't use it in the solution.  Next version (3.2) will have $isArray operator as well.   I don't know what you mean by $ifNull not working "exactly" - so can't comment on that.

Comment: I mean, I thought `$ifNull` would be worked like on documentation `{ $ifNull: [ <expression>, <replacement-expression-if-null> ] }` . However it didn't replace the expression like your codes the above.  Could you please tell me if there is an alternative operator for me ? (because of there is no longer `$size` operator)

Comment: I've solved by using `'s': { $cond: [{$eq: ['$solved', []] }, [ { point: 0 } ], '$solved'] }` .  Thanks anyway...

Comment: $ifNull only replaces "null" type values (missing or null) it is *not* supposed to replace [ ] value as that is very different from null.

Comment: Thank you @AsyaKamsky and I want to apologize to you because of that false alarm. After worked 11 hours I thought that I encountered with a bug. And another mistake about `$size` operator regarding with my English grammer. I'm sorry, again for unneccessary traffic on both here and Jira. 
Have a nice day..

Answer (score 2):

$lookup then $unwind inside look up array and that could be empty

```
  let posts = await Post.aggregate<ActivityDoc>([
    {
      $match: {
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id),
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'users',
        localField: 'user',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'user',
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: '$user',
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: '$user.follower',
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
      },
    },
    {
      $match: {
        $or: [
          {
            $and: [
              {
                'privacy.mode': {
                  $eq: PrivacyMode.EveryOne,
                },
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            $and: [
              {
                'privacy.mode': {
                  $eq: PrivacyMode.MyCircle,
                },
              },
              {
                'user.follower.id': {
                  $eq: req.currentUser?.id,
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  ]);
```