# Unwind empty array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

This is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895006/unwind-empty-array), however, when using a similar approach, I keep getting a list of only the documents that contain subdocuments.

I have a simple schema with questions that can be up and down voted. My schema (I removed some fields for simplicity):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var voteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  value: Number,
});

// Document schema for polls
exports.PollSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    question: { type: String, required: true },
    votes: [voteSchema],
});
```

I want to have a list with all questions and their respective score. A score is the sum of the  'value' field in voteSchema.

I'm trying to use $cond to make sure the empty votes document is replaced with at least one vote subdocument with a value of 0. Unfortunately, when using it, all my totalScore fields are 0. If not using it, I get the correct totalScore, but only for the non empty ones.

```
Poll.aggregate([
    { $project: {
        _id: 1,
        question: 1,
        totalScore : 1,
        votes : { $cond : [ { $eq : ["$votes.length", 0]}, '$votes', [ { value : 0} ]] }
    }},
    { $unwind: "$votes" },
    { $group: {
        _id : "$_id",
        question: { $first: "$question" },
        totalScore : { $sum: "$votes.value" }
    }},
], function(error, polls) {
    console.dir(polls);
});
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If your empty `votes` is `null` (not exists), try to use:

```
{ $ifNull : [ "$votes", [ { value : 0 } ] ] }
```

instead of:

```
{ $cond : [ { $eq : [ "$votes.length", 0 ] }, '$votes', [ { value : 0 } ] ] }
```

If your empty `votes` is `[]` (empty array):

```
{ $cond : [ { $eq : [ "$votes", [] ] }, [ { value : 0 } ], '$votes' ] }
```

And some about `$cond` operator:

Its **syntax**: `{ $cond: [ <boolean-expression>, <true-case>, <false-case> ] }`.

But **you used it**, like: `{ $cond: [ <boolean-expression>, <false-case>, <true-case> ] }`.

If `votes` not exists or empty array (boolean condition is **true**) you should use `[ { value : 0} ]` instead of it (paste `[ { value : 0} ]` in **2** item of `$cond` operator array).
Also, `length` property is not accessable in this case.

Comment: Silly me. Thanks a lot.

This did the trick:

    votes : { $cond : [ { $eq : ["$votes", [] ]}, [ { value : 0} ], '$votes'] }

Comment: What if I need to check if the array is either null or empty?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check for all: **empty array**, **null** and **empty** values you can do like this:

```
{
  $cond: [
    {
      $in: [
        "$my_array",
        [
          null,
          undefined,
          []
        ]
      ]
    },
    "inCaseTrueValue",
    "inCaseFalseValue"
  ]
}
```