# MongoDb Pipeline Aggregation $unwind sub sub documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to list unwind a nested array using MongoDb.

A product contains tasks, each task can have **zero, one or more** subTasks.

Here is a sample product document:

```
db.products.find({_id: ObjectId("554a13d4b692088a38f01f3b")})
```

Result:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("554a13d4b692088a38f01f3b"),
"title" : "product title",
"order" : 3,
"description" : "Description here ",
"status" : "live",
"tasks" : [ 
    {
        "title" : "task 1",
        "description" : "task 1 desc",
        "order" : 10,
        "_id" : ObjectId("554a13d4b692088a38f01f3a"),
        "status" : "live",
        "subTasks" : [ 
            {
                "title" : "task 1 sub 1",
                "content" : "aaa",
                "order" : -2,
                "_id" : ObjectId("554a13d4b692088a38f01f5a"),
                "status" : "live"
            }, 
            {
                "title" : "task 1 sub 2",
                "content" : "aaa",
                "order" : 1,
                "_id" : ObjectId("554a13d4b692088a38f01f3a"),
                "status" : "live"
            }, 
            {
                "title" : "task 1 sub 4",
                "content" : "aaa",
                "order" : 8,
                "_id" : ObjectId("554a13d4b692088a38f01f4a"),
                "status" : "live"
            }, 
            {
                "title" : "task 1 sub 3 ",
                "content" : "aaa",
                "order" : 2,
                "_id" : ObjectId("5550d0a61662211332d9a973"),
                "status" : "live"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "title" : "task 2",
        "description" : "task desc 2",
        "order" : 1,
        "_id" : ObjectId("5550855f9ee2db4e3958d299"),
        "status" : "live",
        "subTasks" : [ 
            {
                "title" : "task 2 sub 1",
                "content" : "bbb",
                "order" : 1,
                "_id" : ObjectId("55508f459ee2db4e3958d29a"),
                "status" : "live"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "title" : "task 3",
        "description" : "task 3 desc",
        "order" : 2,
        "_id" : ObjectId("5551b844bb343a620f85f323"),
        "status" : "live",
        "subTasks" : [ 
            {
                "title" : "task 3 sub 2",
                "content" : "cccc",
                "order" : 0,
                "_id" : ObjectId("5551b88abb343a620f85f324"),
                "status" : "live"
            }, 
            {
                "title" : "task 3 sub 4",
                "content" : "cccc",
                "order" : 1,
                "_id" : ObjectId("5551b8f1bb343a620f85f325"),
                "status" : "hidden"
            }, 
            {
                "title" : "task 3 sub 3",
                "content" : "ccc",
                "order" : 2,
                "_id" : ObjectId("5551ba40bb343a620f85f327"),
                "status" : "hidden"
            }, 
            {
                "title" : "task 3 sub 1",
                "content" : "cccc",
                "order" : -1,
                "_id" : ObjectId("5551bcb8c31283c051d30b7c"),
                "status" : "hidden"
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

The aggregation pipeline work greatly for sorting the tasks & tasks.subTask (using task.order & task.subTasks.order) thanks to [n9code](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3264192/n9code) on previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30190555/mongodb-pipeline-aggregation-sorting-sub-sub-documents/).

Sometimes the tasks have **no** subtasks, eg:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("554a13d4b692088a38f01f3b"),
"title" : "product title",
"order" : 3,
"description" : "Description here ",
"status" : "live",
"tasks" : [ 
    {
        "title" : "task 1",
        "description" : "task 1 desc",
        "order" : 10,
        "_id" : ObjectId("554a13d4b692088a38f01f3a"),
        "status" : "live",
        "subTasks" : [ 
            {
                "title" : "task 1 sub 1",
                "content" : "aaa",
                "order" : -2,
                "_id" : ObjectId("554a13d4b692088a38f01f5a"),
                "status" : "live"
            }, 
            {
                "title" : "task 1 sub 2",
                "content" : "aaa",
                "order" : 1,
                "_id" : ObjectId("554a13d4b692088a38f01f3a"),
                "status" : "live"
            }, 
            {
                "title" : "task 1 sub 4",
                "content" : "aaa",
                "order" : 8,
                "_id" : ObjectId("554a13d4b692088a38f01f4a"),
                "status" : "live"
            }, 
            {
                "title" : "task 1 sub 3 ",
                "content" : "aaa",
                "order" : 2,
                "_id" : ObjectId("5550d0a61662211332d9a973"),
                "status" : "live"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "title" : "task 2",
        "description" : "task desc 2",
        "order" : 1,
        "_id" : ObjectId("5550855f9ee2db4e3958d299"),
        "status" : "live",
        "subTasks" : [ 

        ]
    }, 
    {
        "title" : "task 3",
        "description" : "task 3 desc",
        "order" : 2,
        "_id" : ObjectId("5551b844bb343a620f85f323"),
        "status" : "live",
        "subTasks" : [ 
            {
                "title" : "task 3 sub 2",
                "content" : "cccc",
                "order" : 0,
                "_id" : ObjectId("5551b88abb343a620f85f324"),
                "status" : "live"
            }, 
            {
                "title" : "task 3 sub 4",
                "content" : "cccc",
                "order" : 1,
                "_id" : ObjectId("5551b8f1bb343a620f85f325"),
                "status" : "hidden"
            }, 
            {
                "title" : "task 3 sub 3",
                "content" : "ccc",
                "order" : 2,
                "_id" : ObjectId("5551ba40bb343a620f85f327"),
                "status" : "hidden"
            }, 
            {
                "title" : "task 3 sub 1",
                "content" : "cccc",
                "order" : -1,
                "_id" : ObjectId("5551bcb8c31283c051d30b7c"),
                "status" : "hidden"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Any help getting the task still to show when they have no children please?

Current aggregation:

```
[
 {$match: {_id: ObjectId("554a13d4b692088a38f01f3b")}}, 
 {$project: {tasks: 1, doc: {title: "$title", order: "$order", description: "$description", status: "$status"}}}, 
 {$unwind: "$tasks"}, 
 {$unwind: "$tasks.subTasks"}, 
 {$sort: {"tasks.subTasks.order": 1, "tasks.order": 1}}, 
 {$project: {doc: 1, task_id: "$tasks._id", tasks_doc: {title: "$tasks.title", description: "$tasks.description", order: "$tasks.order", status: "$tasks.status"}, subTasks: "$tasks.subTasks"}}, 
 {$group: {_id: {_id: "$_id", task_id: "$task_id", doc: "$doc", task_doc: "$tasks_doc"}, subTasks: {$push: "$subTasks"}}}, 
 {$group: {_id: {_id: "$_id._id", doc: "$_id.doc"}, tasks: {$push: {_id: "$_id.task_id", title: "$_id.task_doc.title", description: "$_id.task_doc.description", order: "$_id.task_doc.order", status: "$_id.task_doc.status", subTasks: "$subTasks"}}}}, 
 {$project: {_id: "$_id._id", title: "$_id.doc.title", description: "$_id.doc.description", order: "$_id.doc.order", status: "$_id.doc.status", tasks: 1}}
]
```

Desired result:

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("554a13d4b692088a38f01f3b"),
"title": "product title",
"order": 3,
"description": "Description here ",
"status": "live",
"tasks": [
    {
        "title": "task 2",
        "description": "task desc 2",
        "order": 1,
        "_id": ObjectId("5550855f9ee2db4e3958d299"),
        "status": "live",
        "subTasks": [

        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "task 3",
        "description": "task 3 desc",
        "order": 2,
        "_id": ObjectId("5551b844bb343a620f85f323"),
        "status": "live",
        "subTasks": [
            {
                "title": "task 3 sub 1",
                "content": "cccc",
                "order": -1,
                "_id": ObjectId("5551bcb8c31283c051d30b7c"),
                "status": "hidden"
            },
            {
                "title": "task 3 sub 2",
                "content": "cccc",
                "order": 0,
                "_id": ObjectId("5551b88abb343a620f85f324"),
                "status": "live"
            },
            {
                "title": "task 3 sub 3",
                "content": "ccc",
                "order": 2,
                "_id": ObjectId("5551ba40bb343a620f85f327"),
                "status": "hidden"
            }{
                "title": "task 3 sub 4",
                "content": "cccc",
                "order": 1,
                "_id": ObjectId("5551b8f1bb343a620f85f325"),
                "status": "hidden"
            }
        ]
    }{
        "title": "task 1",
        "description": "task 1 desc",
        "order": 10,
        "_id": ObjectId("554a13d4b692088a38f01f3a"),
        "status": "live",
        "subTasks": [
            {
                "title": "task 1 sub 1",
                "content": "aaa",
                "order": -2,
                "_id": ObjectId("554a13d4b692088a38f01f5a"),
                "status": "live"
            },
            {
                "title": "task 1 sub 2",
                "content": "aaa",
                "order": 1,
                "_id": ObjectId("554a13d4b692088a38f01f3a"),
                "status": "live"
            },
            {
                "title": "task 1 sub 3 ",
                "content": "aaa",
                "order": 2,
                "_id": ObjectId("5550d0a61662211332d9a973"),
                "status": "live"
            },
            {
                "title": "task 1 sub 4",
                "content": "aaa",
                "order": 8,
                "_id": ObjectId("554a13d4b692088a38f01f4a"),
                "status": "live"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB ignores empty or null arrays in `$unwind` step, so first of all you need to replace null or empty array fields with some value, say `"<e>"`.

To do this just add this pipeline stage before `$unwind`ing `subTasks`:

```
$project: {
             doc: 1, 
             tasks: {
                       title: 1, 
                       description: 1, 
                       order: 1, 
                       status: 1, 
                       subTasks: {
                                    $cond: [
                                              {
                                                 $size: "$tasks.subTasks"
                                              }, 
                                              "$tasks.subTasks", 
                                              ['<e>']
                                           ]
                                 }
                     }
           }
```

Then, during `$group`ing you will need to do the opposite, replacing your `"<e>"`, values with empty arrays:

```
$group: {
           _id: {
                   _id: "$_id._id", 
                   doc: "$_id.doc"}, 
                   tasks: {
                             $push: {
                                       _id: "$_id.task_id", 
                                       title: "$_id.task_doc.title", 
                                       description: "$_id.task_doc.description", 
                                       order: "$_id.task_doc.order", 
                                       status: "$_id.task_doc.status", 
                                       subTasks: {
                                                    $cond: [
                                                              {
                                                                 $eq: ["$subTasks", ["<e>"]]
                                                              }, 
                                                              [], 
                                                              "$subTasks"
                                                           ]
                                                  }
                                     }
                           }
                 }
         }
```

So here is your final pipeline:

```
[
   {$match: {_id: ObjectId("554a13d4b692088a38f01f3b")}},
   {$project: {tasks: 1, doc: {title: "$title", order: "$order", description: "$description", status: "$status"}}},
   {$unwind: "$tasks"},
   {$project: {doc: 1, tasks: {title: 1, description: 1, order: 1, status: 1, subTasks: {$cond: [{$size: "$tasks.subTasks"}, "$tasks.subTasks", ['<e>']]}}}},
   {$unwind: "$tasks.subTasks"},
   {$sort: {"tasks.order": -1, "tasks.subTasks.order": 1}},
   {$project: {doc: 1, task_id: "$tasks._id", tasks_doc: {title: "$tasks.title", description: "$tasks.description", order: "$tasks.order", status: "$tasks.status"}, subTasks: "$tasks.subTasks"}},
   {$group: {_id: {_id: "$_id", task_id: "$task_id", doc: "$doc", task_doc: "$tasks_doc"}, subTasks: {$push: "$subTasks"}}},
   {$group: {_id: {_id: "$_id._id", doc: "$_id.doc"}, tasks: {$push: {_id: "$_id.task_id", title: "$_id.task_doc.title", description: "$_id.task_doc.description", order: "$_id.task_doc.order", status: "$_id.task_doc.status", subTasks: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$subTasks", ['<e>']]}, [], "$subTasks"]}}}}},
   {$project: {_id: "$_id._id", title: "$_id.doc.title", description: "$_id.doc.description", order: "$_id.doc.order", status: "$_id.doc.status", tasks: 1}}
]
```

Cheers :)

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Did you find the problem? :)

Comment: Getting a error:

`uncaught exception: aggregate failed: {
 "errmsg" : "exception: Expression $eq takes exactly 2 arguments. 1 were passed in.",
 "code" : 16020,
 "ok" : 0
}`

Comment: Fixed. Big big thank you yo @n9code for helping me out on this issue.  He even helped out via chat!

Comment: Updated to bring through the task_id in the final output

Comment: you have added `id: 1`, did you mean `_id: 1`? if yes, it is set that way by default, unless you specify `_id: 0`.

Comment: Should be _I'd: 1 yep. It doesn't bring the ids through otherwise, took me 2hrs to debug that one lol.

Comment: You can directly use "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true" in your unwind command instead of filling empty arrays see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43110387/how-to-get-all-result-if-unwind-field-does-not-exist-in-mongodb