# MongoDB $lookup if the local field exists

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregate

I have these entities:

```
// collectionA
{
  key: "value",
  ref: SOME-OBJECT-ID
}

// collectionB
{
  _id: SOME-OBJECT-ID
  key1: "value1"
}
```

I want that if **ref** exists in the collectionA entity, it will lookup for it on the collectionB and bring its data.

If the **ref** key is missing or it doesn't missing but the entity in collectionB is missing I get empty result from all of the aggregate query.

This is the aggregate query:

```
{ $match },
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "collectionB",
    let: {
      ref: "$ref"
    },
    pipeline: [
      {
        $match: {
          $expr: {
            $eq: [
              "$_id", "$$ref"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $project: {
          key1: 1
        }
      }
    ],
    as: "someData"
  }
}
```

How can I avoid this or add any conditional $lookup?

Comment: @turivishal How about [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gO7OYuFSYGD) I feel that I am not getting something from OP.

Comment: @Gibbs our both assumptions are different than OP's expectations :)

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing that is adding another `match` at the beginning to skip from `source`

To skip from `B`, you can omit at the end.

```
{$match:{ ref:{$exists:true}}}
```

It will consider only `ref` existing docs.

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pX742eDOwHb)

```
db.A.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      ref: {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "B",
      "localField": "ref",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "output"
    }
  }
])
```

But you don't need to do this if you don't have specific use case, as it will not impact much.

Comment: But I need this only if `ref` exists... there other entries that are okay to be pulled when `ref` doesn't exists, so you basically tell me not to pull them at all and only pull those entities have `ref`. Please also notice that I need to project the key1 from the foreign collection (collection B) so it has to be declared using pipelines as I showed.

Answer (score 0):

I have found it. The document was not selected because I have used the `$unwind` - and it won't return the document if we are trying to do it on an empty array. So this is the fix:

```
{
  $unwind: {
    path: "$ref",
    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
  }
}
```

Instead of:

```
{
  $unwind: "$ref"
}
```

I found the `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` from this answer [How to get all result if unwind field does not exist in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43110387/how-to-get-all-result-if-unwind-field-does-not-exist-in-mongodb)

Comment: I really don't know why MongoDB doesn't handle this implementation of unwind as the default. Also why they call it $unwind instead of just parseArray or something more meaningful? Also, why they call it project instead of keep the naming of limitFields from the regular find operations? And also, why they use this un easier syntax with the $ and $$... ? Hope they make those things easier.

Answer (score 0):

You should match zero documents in the [`lookup`'s subquery pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-subqueries-on-a-joined-collection), if the local field doesn't exist. You do this by using the [`$cond`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator and passing `null` to the [`$match`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage (the [`$type`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/type/) operator returns `'missing'` if a field doesn't exist):

```js
{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'collectionB',
    let: {
      ref: '$ref'
    },
    pipeline: [
      {$match: {
        $expr: {
          $cond: {
            if: { $eq: [{ $type: "$$ref" }, "missing"] },
            then: {$literal: null},
            else: {$eq: ['$_id', '$$ref']}
          }
        }
      }}
    ],
    as: 'someData'
  }
}
```

A related answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53711339/11053968).