# $lookup with deeply nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, lookup, aggregation

I am new to MongoDB and currently working on a recipe App for school which suggests diet plans. Therefore I need to join the "meal" ObjectId in the diet plan of the user (collection "Users") with the ObjectIds in the collections "Meals".

Afterwards I need to join an "ingredient" ObjectID in the "Meals" collection with the ID of the "ingredient" in the "Ingredients" collection. The problem is, that the "ingredient" ObjectID in collection "Meals" is situated in an Object with another integer variable "amount". This object is nested in an array called "ingredients" with many objects such as the one just described.

Below is my Structure:

**Users**

```
{
 "_id": ObjectId("5b28cab902f28e18b863bd36"),
 "username: "testUser1",
 "password": "$2a$08$KjddpaSQPjp6aF/gseOhVeddYdqWJCJ4DpFwxfNgsk81G.0TOtN5i",
 "dietPlans": Object
    {
     "dietPlanCurrent":Object
         {
          "monday":Object
               {
               "breakfast":Object
                    {
                     "meal": ObjectId("5b2b9a8bbda339352cc39ec4")
                 },
                 … 
           },
           … 
     },
     …
  },
}
```

**Meals**

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5b2b9a8bbda339352cc39ec4"),
   "name": "Gulasch-breakfast",
   "cuisine": "International",
   "ingredients":[
       {
            "ingredient": ObjectId("5b1ec0f939b55efcd4e28a2d"),
            "amount": 20
       },
       {
            "ingredient": ObjectId("5b1ec42474fc1f58d84264d4"),
            "amount": 20
       },
       {
            "ingredient": ObjectId("5b1ec42474fc1f58d84264d5"),
            "amount": 20
       },
       …   
    ],

   "comments": [
        …
    ]
}
```

**Ingredients**

```
{ 
    {
     "_id": ObjectId("5b1ec0f939b55efcd4e28a2d"),
     "name": "Walnut",
     "calories": 654
      … 
    }
    {
     "_id": ObjectId("5b1ec0f939b55efcd4e28a3d"),
     "name": "Apple",
     "calories": 123
     … 
    }
… 
}
```

What I am trying to get is:

```
    {
 "_id": ObjectId("5b28cab902f28e18b863bd36"),
 "username: "testUser1",
 "password": "$2a$08$KjddpaSQPjp6aF/gseOhVeddYdqWJCJ4DpFwxfNgsk81G.0TOtN5i",
 "dietPlans": Object
    {
     "dietPlanCurrent":Object
         {
          "Monday":Object
               {
               "breakfast":Object
                    {
                     "meal": ObjectId("5b2b9a8bbda339352cc39ec4")
                     "matchedIngredients": [
                        {
                         "_id": ObjectId("5b1ec0f939b55efcd4e28a2d"),
                         "name": "Walnut",
                         "calories": 654
                         … 
                        }
                      … 
                      ]

                 },


                 … 
           },


           … 
     },
     …
  },
}
```

**My approach which is not working (only returning empty matchedIngredients Array)**

```
    {
        $match: {
            '_id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.userId)
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup:   {
            from: 'meals',
            localField: 'dietPlans.dietPlanCurrent.monday.breakfast.meal',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: "dietPlans.dietPlanCurrent.monday.breakfast.mealObject"
        }              
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$dietPlans.dietPlanCurrent.monday.breakfast.mealObject",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
    },
   {
        $unwind: {
               path: "$dietPlans.dietPlanCurrent.monday.breakfast.mealObject.ingredients",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup:   {
            from: 'ingredients',
            localField: 'dietPlans.dietPlanCurrent.monday.breakfast.mealObject.ingredients.ingredient',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: "dietPlans.dietPlanCurrent.monday.breakfast.matchedIngredients"
        }              
    }
```

Help is very much appreciated. I already checked out this approach, but it somehow didn't work:

[Approach that didn't work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36022456/mongodb-lookup-on-nested-document)

Thank you very much!

Comment: what is your mongodb version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible with mongodb version **3.4** but if you upgrade to **3.6** then you can try below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.userId) } },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Meals.collection.name,
    "let": { "meal_id": "$dietPlans.dietPlanCurrent.monday.breakfast.meal" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$_id", "$$meal_id" ] } } },
      { "$unwind": "$ingredients" },
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": Ingredients.collection.name,
        "let": { "ingredient_id": "$ingredients.ingredient" },
        "pipeline": [
          { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$_id", "$$ingredient_id" ] } } }
        ],
        "as": "matchedIngredients"
      }},
      { "$unwind": "$ingredients.matchedIngredients" },
      { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "name": { "$first":"$name" },
        "cuisine": { "$first":"$cuisine" },
        "ingredients": { "$push":"$ingredients" }
      }}
    ],
    "as": "dietPlans.dietPlanCurrent.monday.breakfast.mealObject"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$dietPlans.dietPlanCurrent.monday.breakfast.mealObject" }
])
```

Comment: please help if you could on related question like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61109179/mongodb-find-deeply-nested-object-with-lookup

Comment: @newdeveloper Sure I will do... It is night here will do in morning

Comment: Thanks in advance !