# How to use $lookup to resolve reference to nested document?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have `energy_carrier` documents that are nested in a collection `energy_ carrier_groups`.
I reference those `energy_carrier` documents from another collection `tech` and would like to resolve the reference with a `$lookup` aggregation.

=> How can I define a sub query inside `$lookup` that preprocesses /unwinds the energy carriers before I do the actual join/lookup?

My preferred way would be to specify a path for the `from` or  `foreignField` option to target the nested documents of the `energy_carrier_groups` collection:

```
"from": "energy_carrier_groups.energy_carriers"
```

or

```
"from": "energy_carrier_groups"
"foreignField": "energy_carriers._id".
```

However, that does not seem to work.

I found that `$lookup` supports `let` and `pipeline` arguments as an alternative to the options `localField` and `foreignField` (since Version 3.6) and that might be the way to go.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-subqueries-on-a-joined-collection

Since version 5.0 its also possible to combine all four options:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#correlated-subqueries-using-concise-syntax

(A requirement for mongodb version 5.0 is a CPU that supports AVX and mine doesn't.)

All that options make knots in my head! Could you please tell me how I should formulate the pipeline to resolve my reference from tech to energy carrier? Can't be that difficult, could it?

Code to create some example data:

```
import bson
from pymongo import MongoClient


def unique_id():
    return bson.objectid.ObjectId()


client = MongoClient(host='localhost', port=27017)
database = client.forecast

referenced_id = unique_id()

# create referenced collection
energy_carrier_groups = database.energy_carrier_groups
energy_carrier_groups.delete_many({})
energy_carrier_groups.insert_many([
    {
        '_id': unique_id(),
        'name': 'fuels',
        'energy_carriers': [
            {
                '_id': referenced_id,
                'name': 'oil'
            },
            {
                '_id': unique_id(),
                'name': 'gas'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        '_id': unique_id(),
        'name': 'electricity',
        'energy_carriers': [
            {
                '_id': unique_id(),
                'name': 'green electricity'
            },
            {
                '_id': unique_id(),
                'name': 'conventional electricity'
            }
        ]
    },

])

# create referencing collection
tech = database.tech
tech.delete_many({})
tech.insert_many([
    {
        '_id': unique_id(),
        'name': 'qux',
        'energy_carrier': referenced_id
    },

])
```

Expected result of my aggregation:

```
{
    '_id': ObjectId('6183de1b5dd889cfcdeaa711'), 
    'name': 'qux', 
    'energy_carrier': {
        '_id': ObjectId('6183de1b5dd889cfcdeaa70b'), 
        'name': 'oil'
    }
}
```

First trial, using a path to the nested document:

```
pipeline = [
    {"$match": {"name": 'qux'}},
    {"$lookup": {
       "from": "$energy_carrier_groups.energy_carriers", # <= does not work 
       "localField": "energy_carrier",
       "foreignField": "_id",
       "as": "energy_carrier"
      }
    },
    {"$unwind": "$energy_carrier"},  # transforms lookup result array to a single entry
]
results = referencing.aggregate(pipeline)

for result in results:
    print(result)

print('finished')
```

Another trial, using `let` and `pipeline` instead of `localField` and `foreignField`:

```
pipeline = [
    {"$match": {"name": 'qux'}},
    {"$lookup": {
       "from": "energy_carrier_groups",
       "let": {"tech_energy_carrier_id": "$energy_carrier"},
       "pipeline": [
           {"$unwind": "$energy_carriers"},
           {"$match": {"$expr": {"$eq": ["$$tech_energy_carrier_id", "$energy_carriers._id"]}}}
       ],
       "as": "energy_carrier"  # overrides id field with an array wrapping the resolved reference
      }
    },
    {"$unwind": "$energy_carrier"},  # transforms array to a single entry
]
results = tech.aggregate(pipeline)

for result in results:
    print(result)

print('finished')
```

Gives some result but resolves the reference with "filtered energy carrier groups" instead of resolving only the energy carrier.

**=> What is the recommended way to resolve the referenced energy carrier for tech?**

**=> If there is a better No-Sql Database then MongoDb for this porpose, please let me know, too**

**Related**:

https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/81175/is-there-an-alternative-to-mongodb-that-allows-to-easily-resolve-document-refere

[MongoDB $lookup on nested document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36022456/mongodb-lookup-on-nested-document)

[$lookup on ObjectId's in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967482/lookup-on-objectids-in-an-array)

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-subqueries-on-a-joined-collection

https://www.stackchief.com/tutorials/%24lookup%20Examples%20%7C%20MongoDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A. Here is another version, based on my initial trial to use *lookup* and combined with the *addFields* trick of turivishal to override/correct the resulting property *energy_carrier*.

```
pipeline = [
    {"$match": {"name": 'qux'}},
    {"$lookup": {
       "from": "energy_carrier_groups",
       "let": {"energy_carrier_id": "$energy_carrier"},  # executed on tech
       "pipeline": [  # executed on energy_carrier_groups, with the knowledge of let definition
           {"$unwind": "$energy_carriers"},
           {"$match": {"$expr": {"$eq": ["$$energy_carrier_id", "$energy_carriers._id"]}}}
       ],
       "as": "energy_carrier"  # already includes what we want but also extra fields
      }
    },
    {"$addFields": {  # overrides/corrects the result of the previous stage with parts of it
        "energy_carrier": {"$first": "$energy_carrier.energy_carriers"}
    }
  }
]
results = tech.aggregate(pipeline)
```

B. Alternatives to MongoDb (e.g. RethinkDb) might be better suited for complex queries

Also see
https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/81175/is-there-an-alternative-to-mongodb-that-allows-to-easily-resolve-document-refere

Answer (score 1):

You can try,

- `let` to pass `energy_carrier` id to pipeline
- `$match` to check expression condition using `$in` operator, is `energy_carrier` in `energy_carriers._id`
- `$project` to show required fields
- `$filter` to iterate loop of `energy_carriers` array and filter by variable
  `energy_carrier` passed in `let`
- `$first` to get the first element from above filtered result
- `$addFields` and `$first` to get the first element from the above lookup result

```
pipeline = [
  { $match: { name: "qux" } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "energy_carrier_groups",
      let: { energy_carrier: "$energy_carrier" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: { $expr: { $in: ["$$energy_carrier", "$energy_carriers._id"] } }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            energy_carriers: {
              $first: {
                $filter: {
                  input: "$energy_carriers",
                  cond: { $eq: ["$$energy_carrier", "$$this._id"] }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "energy_carrier"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: { energy_carrier: { $first: "$energy_carrier.energy_carriers" } }
  }
]

results = tech.aggregate(pipeline)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gjx-du9_WSB)

Comment: Thank you! This yields the expected result. At the same time, it seems to be quite a complex solution for a "simple" task. If that is the recommended solution, mongodb aggregations seem to have a poor API.

Comment: If you know a better No-SqL Database for this purpose, please let me know, too: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/81175/is-there-an-alternative-to-mongodb-that-allows-to-easily-resolve-document-refere

Comment: Yes, of course, this is a complex solution, but there are no other simple ways to achieve your requirement on this database schema structure. I can not say mongodb has poor API but you have to improve your schema structure, reduce collections/tables, means avoid lookup/join.

Comment: Is it ok to duplicate data in a NoSQL database, Suppose you have 50 tables in a SQL database, coming to NoSQL world, you should probably cut them down to 5 or 10 tables, depending on the trade-off between performance and storage, Higher performance requires more storage. But today storage is cheaper and cheaper. So denormalization has the bigger advantage.

Comment: Its not only about performance and storage but also maintenance effort of redundant model structures and consistency. I already try to apply references sparingly. Let's say I put everything in a single, huge collection with > 50 nested levels. If I would like to replace an energy carrier at 1000 different locations, the corresponding aggregation query would get even more complex. If I model the energy carrier groups by tags instead of parent document, I would have to ensure that those unique tags are used propertly. Maybe I need to learn more about validation/how to use kind of "enum" values.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why MongoDb does not support paths in "from" or "foreignField" properties? That would make the API usage more powerful/efficient?

Comment: *why MongoDb does not support paths in "from" or "foreignField" properties?*  => because mongodb is no-sql, it can not recognize the reference collection, and can't join nested collection by path. for suggest or improvement or questions you can post the topic in [mongodb developer forum](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/).

Comment: It seems that the first stage of the lookup pipline (=$match) can be removed without influencing the result.

Comment: $unwind will deconstruct the array, for ex: if one document's array has 10 elements then it will generate 10 root documents after unwind, so it is so expensive transaction, it will occupy more memory and more process.

Comment: The first $match stage is to filter main documents, and the better option is to filter elements as per condition in any projection stage.